# EditText txt_expense=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expense); EditText txt_amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);

Tags: android

```
 EditText txt_expense=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expense);
 EditText txt_amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
```

If i write these lines in the class brackets my app stops working while if i write same thing under any function ie button it goes well .

Am i missing something ?

the class extends `Activity`

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to declare `txt_expense` and `txt_amount` as global variables as follows :

```
public EditText txt_expense,txt_amount;
```

Then on your `onCreate()` you do this :

```
txt_expense=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expense);
txt_amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
```

And then on your method you just do something like :

```
txt_expense.setText("BLABLA");
txt_amount.setText("BLEBLE");
```

And it should work